# Force Reinstantiate a Fragment from Existing Object

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I don't know if the title is clear, but what I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a ListView - [a drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to be exact. It should contain a list of Fragment titles from my app and each list item, when clicked, should open the Fragment itself in the main app area.

Now I've successfully created an adapter of custom `DrawerItem` objects, where each object has the following 2 members:

`String title`, `Fragment fragment`.

The `fragment` I fill with new instances of my fragments, the `title` with each Fragment's title (retrieved from string resources).

All works fine up until the part where I try to add the `fragment` to the main content area. It works the first time, but when the same fragment is selected the second time in the `ListView` the app crashes with `Fragment already added` error.

My guess is that a single instantiated Fragment object may only be added once to the layout (using `FragmentTransaction`, since this is what I use to add it). That's why the second attempt fails.

So my question is, how do I recreate the fragment object just before it's added to the layout; or how do I preserve only its class name so I can instantiate it just before adding it to the layout.

Comment: *That's why the second attempt fails.* You can't add again a fragment that is already added to a container(you're not doing any replace transactions?). *how do I recreate the fragment object just before it's added to the layout;* - it's not clear how do you want to manage the added fragments(especially if you want to allow BACK to revert through the added fragments). You can use `add()` once at the first selection followed by `detach/attach` transactions on future selections.

Comment: I don't want to manage added fragments. I need to remove/detach the old one and add a new fragment on its place, even if the fragment being removed and the one being added are of the same fragment class.

Comment: Then use a `replace()` transaction and not an `add()` transaction. Also, don't keep references to the `Fragment` object itself in the `DrawerItem` objects, you just need to keep/store the name of the fragment class. That name you'll use it with one of the `Fragment.instantiate()` methods to make a new instance of the fragment each time.

Comment: @Luksprog your suggestion is the best one so far. I think I will go this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do it that way:

- My ListView adapter would hold only String or String and id Objects.
- on item click i would check which element was clicked and then create appropriate frgment instance and replece it in fragment manager

Comment: Ok, but how do I turn a String to a Fragment object? Should I keep the fragment's class names as strings?

Comment: I was more like `if(string.equals("name")) fragment = new NameFragment()` etc.

Comment: Not very useful, since I have to maintain two lists this way - one for the array of fragment names to be put in the list and one with the multiple `if`s you are suggesting.

Comment: Then maybe you can store class name in Class<?> object in list element and then create a new object from that class